# FullCalendar not displaying events

Tags: javascript, php, html, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I'm still new to fullCalendar and I am trying to display events that are retrieved from a Mysql database. The structure of my table is as follows:

[image]

The content of my table is as follows:

[image]

Below is the script I used to generate the fullCalendar:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                editable:true,
                header:{
                left:'prev, next today',
                center:'title',
                right:'month, agendaWeek, agendaDay'
                },
                //events: 'loadCalendarEvents.php'
                events: function(start, end, timezone, callback){
                  $.ajax({
                    url: 'loadCalendarEvents.php',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {
                    },
                    success: function(data){
                      var events = [];
                  
                      for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                        events.push({
                          title: data[i]['class'],
                          start: data[i]['start_event'],
                          end: data[i]['end_event'],
                        });
                      }
                    }
                  });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Below is the file that adds the events (loadCalendarEvents.php):

```
<?php
    include("db.php");//Includes the database file that makes the connection
    $timetable = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT class, start_event, end_event  FROM lecturertimetable");//Loading events for the calendar
    $myArray = array();
    if ($timetable->num_rows > 0) {
        // To output the data of each row
        while($row = $timetable->fetch_assoc()) {
            $myArray[] = $row;
        }
    } 
    echo json_encode($myArray);
?>
```

However, none of the events are getting displayed and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your HTML page renders FullCalendar javascript on page load. So at that time you do not have any events. (Because the browser has to make a request to the `loadCalendarEvents.php` to get the events.)

You can solve this in three ways.

1. Create the JSON object for the events in your controller and pass as a parameters.
2. Make an AJAX Request to `loadCalendarEvents.php` and on success, load the events to the calendar.
3. Make an AJAX request to `loadCalendarEvents.php` and on success, render the fullCalendar.

Following code sends an AJAX call to get the events from `loadCalendarEvents.php`.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
         $.ajax({
            url: 'loadCalendarEvents.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
               // If you have some data to send to loadCalendarEvents.php
                id: 1,
                name: "hello"
             },
             success: function(data) {
                  var events = [];
                  
                  for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                       events.push({
                            title: data[i]['class'],
                            start: data[i]['start_event'],
                            end: data[i]['end_event'],
                       });
                   }

                   //adding the callback
                   callback(events);
              }
         });
     }
 });
```

Comment: thank you so much for your reply. Regarding point 1, isn't that what the line `echo json_encode($myArray);` does? If not could you please show me an example?

Comment: Yes, but you have to wait for the response. I have updated my answer with the code. I haven't tested this. You might have to do some tweaks, but you can get an idea from this.

Comment: I have updated my script based on what you mentioned but it still doesn't work. I kept the part that sends data to loadCalendarEvents.php empty as I don't want to send any data but even when I was sending data, it wasn't working. Could you please give my updated code a look and let me know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: By console you mean on screen right? if so then nope, no errors are showing when I run the main file. I even tried to put a print_r statement in the loadCalendarEvents.php and only run this file and it was reading the arrays fine. It is just not displaying anything on the calendar.

Comment: @Soit Console means the console feature in your browser which lets you see logs and errors coming from JavaScript. Open your browser's Developer Tools to view it. You can also use the Network tool to view the raw response coming from the PHP when the Ajax call runs, and check there are no PHP errors or other unexpected output.

Comment: You also need to provide the events to fullCalendar via the `callback`...

Comment: @Dula checked the console and there were no errors. I also checked the Networks tab and whenever I change the calendar page, the loadCalendarEvents.php page appears under the name tab. Once I click on it to expand it it shows the arrays. Unfortunately this still doesn't show on the calendar

Comment: That's because you're not using the callback to pass the data to fullCalendar, as I mentioned above

Comment: @ADyson isn't this what we did in this line `events: function(start, end, timezone, callback)` or no. If no could you please let me know how to do that?

Comment: @Soit - I am sorry, I missed to add the callback. I updated the code accordingly.

Comment: `isn't this what we did`...that just defines the callback. It doesn't _use_ it.

Comment: @Dula yup, works perfectly now after adding the callback. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: @ADyson ya that seemed to be the reason behind this issue. Thank you so much for pointing that out

Answer (score 2):

I note from the [original version of your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70058983/revisions) that you were originally simply specifying the data feed as

```
events: 'loadCalendarEvents.php'
```

There's nothing wrong with that approach - it's [documented by fullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/events-json-feed). FullCalendar will automatically send an AJAX request to that URL whenever it needs to fetch events.

The only problem you had with that version was the incorrect naming of the class, start_event and end_event fields - you need to call them `title`, `start` and `end` precisely to match the [names required by fullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/event-object), otherwise it won't recognise or use them, and of course an event without a recognised time and no description cannot be shown on a calendar.

There are two possible fixes for that:

1. Simply rename your database columns to `title`, `start` and `end`.
2. Use PHP to create an array with the fields named correctly:

Code:

```
while($row = $timetable->fetch_assoc()) {
    $myArray[] = array(
      "title" => $row["class"],
      "start" => $row["start_event"],
      "end" => $row["end_event"],
    );
}
```

N.B. You should also (as per the documentation) amend the PHP so it takes notice of the `start` and `end` parameters automatically appended to the request by fullCalendar, and restrict your SQL query to only returning events which fall between those dates. That way fullCalendar will only be given the data it actually needs, without inefficiently downloading (potentially) years of historical data which the user isn't going to look at.

---

P.S. If you're just getting started with fullCalendar I'd recommend using the latest version 5, rather than the version 3 you seem to have used here. It's got more features, lots of bugs fixed, and its performance has improved. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v5/getting-started

Comment: ooh that makes perfect sense. However, the `=>` gives me an error and I can't find any source that explains why it is not working. Also thank you so much for spending time and explaining the issue I had. Sorry I can't upvote your answer, as I don't have enough reputation but it really explained a lot of things

Comment: Actually I've just realised it's a typo... `$array` should be `array`. I've corrected the example, it should work now

Comment: Ohh, got it. Thank you so much for your time. That was really helpful. Much appreciated